# How get attributes from object php?

Tags: php, arrays, object

There is object from XML, I try to get attributes for each item:

- Code
- String(value)

I tried to get **code** attribute from *$cbr_xml->course[0]*:

```
 foreach($cbr_xml->course[0] as $key => $currency){
      var_dump($currency['code'][$key]); // get
}
```

The object after `var_dump($currency);` in loop:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#321 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(7) "11.1000"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#324 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(3) "EUR"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(7) "12.5763"
}
```

Comment: `$currency['code']` is a string, so `$currency['code'][$key]` will return a character in that string, probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the attributes with the following code:

```
foreach($cbr_xml->course[0] as $single_element){
  foreach($single_element->attributes() as $attr_key=>$attr_value) {
    if($attr_key=='code') { echo $attr_value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how get also `string(7) "12.5763"`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `@attributes`

like this:

`$currency->attributes()['code']`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the array dereference:

```
echo $currency['code'];
```